# Assigning value to session, giving object reference not set to an instance of an object exception in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, session, controller

**Problem Statement:**

I'm trying to assign a value to session object in MVC Controller it is giving exception as **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

I'm having two controllers

1. **MainController**
2. **SecondaryController**

When I assign value to session in Main controller it is working fine.but if i assign same value in a **Test()** method in secondary controller,it is giving error.

What i'm doing wrong here???

**Main Controller :**

```
 public class MainController: Controller
     {
        SecondaryController secCont=new SecondaryController();
        public ActionResult Index(LoginModel loginModel)
          {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                 Session["LogID"] = 10;
                  //This is working fine.
                  //Instead of this i want call secCont.Test(); method where value for session assigned, it is giving error.

                }
              return View(loginModel);

           }
     }
```

**Secondary Controller :**

```
 public class SecondaryController: Controller
   {
     public void Test()
     {
        Session["LogID"] = 10;
        // Giving Error as **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is because Session variable is only available in `Standard ASP.NET MVC` Controller (main controller). In order to access session variables in secondary controller you should use

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["LogID"] = 10;
```

Comment: Hello. I am having the same problem. I tried referencing System.Web but it still gave me the error That Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Please advise.

Comment: i'M HAVING THE SAME PROBLEM!!

Comment: same thing was happening with me, I was using a controller inside Areas folder, thank you!

Comment: i am having the same problem, and this solution is working for me